# Confusion with chess pieces names

Tags: rules

What criteria do they use to give chess pieces names? Wow do they came out with pieces names like king, queen, bishop, knight, rook and pawn?

Comment: I mean the first four were well-known positions in the medieval system.

Comment: They're cultural. The names you use are English. The piece called a Bishop in English is a "runner" in German, and a "fool" in French. The German word for Pawn translates as "farmer." The names you know are just pulled from the context of the culture you're in.